# Wrong class in netbeans generated Resource Map Code for dialogs

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

There seems to be a bug in netbeans 6.9.1 when it generates the ResourceMap code. My project is called ScriptedResponseApp and the main entry is ScriptedResponseAppView. So, for all the dialogs, I should get something like

```
org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap resourceMap =Application.getInstance(ScriptedResponseApp.class).getContext().getResourceMap(SomeDialogClass.class)
```

but instead I get

```
org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap resourceMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(scriptedresponseapp.ConsoleView.class).getContext().getResourceMap(SomeDialogClass.class);
```

Where ConsoleView is another unrelated class in my project. Why is netbeans picking ConsoleView up as my main class and how do I fix it? As a work around, I've been closing netbeans, editing the code in a text editor, and reopening netbeans. It work until I make a change to anything involving a resource file, which generates out this same wrong code.

Any ideas on how to fix this annoying bug?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it's a bug. In my case, I refactored the main class, but Netbeans don't change the project.xml (nbproject folder).

I mannualy change  and it worked.